# Returning to another class after action listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have two classes, class A and B. Class A has method A1 and class B has main method and another method B1.

ClassA :

```
public static void A1()
{

   B.main(null);   
   do some other work....;  

}
```

ClassB :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setResizable(false);
            f.add(new B1(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        });
    }



  public B1() {
            List population = some list;

            iterator = population.iterator();
            next = iterator.next();

            new Timer(17, new ActionListener() {
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   if(!iterator.hasNext())
                   {
                      **return to A1;**
                   }
                   else
                   {
                            do some work...;

                   }
              }).start();     

        }
}
```

How do I return to A1? I have tried exiting the jframe and system.exit but all seem to stop the execution of the entire program. I need the program to return to A1 and continue from there, when there are no more elements in the list 'population' in class B1.

Comment: *How do I get this done?*  **Get what done?** *system.exit* can see this is your code, but yeah it teminates the JVM

Comment: I need the program to return to A1 and continue from there, when there are no more elements in the list 'population' in class B1.

Comment: So why do you have a timer? Why do you have a ActionListener? what is wrong with `return;`

Comment: The ActionListener is for carrying out an animation. I tried return; but it simply does nothing. It doesn't execute the rest of the code in A1

Comment: This smells of being an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you're asking "how do I solve X", when the real solution is to use a completely different approach, Y. I wonder if you really want to use a modal dialog such as a JDialog, or perhaps simply swap JPanel views with a CardLayout, but I'm having a hard time guessing what the underlying goal is. Consider telling us this, not how you're trying to solve it because I fear your approach looks to be wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should consider having a look into the "observer pattern"